# Simulator to simulate the intereference between light and the wave produced by an electron driven by the light

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, refraction, interference, simulations

When an electromagnetic wave reaches an electron the electron will oscillate creating it's own electromagnetic wave which will interfere with the original electromagnetic wave. I am looking for a free simulation software to model this scenario. Thanks!